# subcaptions on a multi image figure (one page) - wish to count only as one figure

Tags: graphics

I wish to place 4 images in one figure (and sometimes only 2 images in 1 figure).
Is there a way to put a small note under each figure like (a) or (top-left)?

```
\begin{figure*}
 \begin{minipage}[b]{0.99\linewidth}
 \centering
 \includegraphics[width=2.90 in]{fig30.png}
 \includegraphics[width=2.90 in]{fig31.png}\\
\vspace{0.5cm}
 \end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.99\linewidth}
\centering
 \includegraphics[width=2.90 in]{fig32.png}
 \includegraphics[width=2.90 in]{fig33.png}
\caption{test}
\label{fig:fig30}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure*}
```

Also, how do I modify the solution below so that I get the images stacked vertically. If I delete the 2nd half of the image calls, They come out stacked horizontally, but I haven't figured out how to get them to come out vertically stacked.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Use the `subfigure` environment, from `subcaption`, for each subfigure, and a simple `caption` command, It requires its  width as an argument.

Comment: Thanks! but will those caption commands on each subfigure give me a new figure number? I'm trying to avoid that. Also, if I use /ContinuedFloat, I think the figure number will show up on the 1st subfigure and not the last, if I understand /ContinuedFloat properly.

Comment: The subfigures are numbered (a), (b), (c), (d) by default, and the figure which contains them is `Figure 1`. Please see my answer. For the last point, how do you use `ContinuedFloat`?

Comment: Yes, that is terrific! regarding ContinuedFloat, yes that wasn't working on the mini page - I was thinking of it just to suppress the figure count. your answer looks very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
    \usepackage{caption, subcaption}
    \usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
    \DeclareCaptionLabelFormat{tblr}{\ifcase\value{subfigure}\or(top left) \or (top right) \or (bottom left) \or (bottom right)\fi}
    \captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=tblr}
    \begin{document}

    \begin{figure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
 \includegraphics[width=2.90 in]{fig30.png}
        \caption{image 1}
        \label{subfig:1}
      \end{subfigure}%
      \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
 \includegraphics[width=2.90 in]{fig31.png}
        \caption{image 2}
        \label{subfig:2}
      \end{subfigure}
\bigskip

      \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
 \includegraphics[width=2.90 in]{fig32.png}
        \caption{image 3}
        \label{subfig:3}
      \end{subfigure}
      \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
 \includegraphics[width=2.90 in]{fig33.png}
        \caption{image 4}
        \label{subfig:4}
      \end{subfigure}
      \caption{Four images}
      \label{fig:4images}
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! I'm assuming I can also use something like \vspace{0.5 cm} if I want something other than a big skip?

Comment: That's correct. And if you want only (a), (b), &c. without any text, just use `\caption{}`.

Comment: If there are only two pictures in the figure, is it possible and not too much trouble to change the lettering from (a) (b) to (left) (right) or (top) (bottom)

Comment: I've posted a solution to your last requirement, for 4 images, which can easily be adapted to the case of two subfigures. It suffices to declare a new label format.

Comment: Thanks! I would not have easily found that.

Comment: Actually, there's a problem with the cross-references (it displays `fig. 1c` for instance, instead of `fig. 1 (bottom left)`. I'll think about it tomorrow.